# How to solve for the limits of an integral?

Tags: python, sympy

I have this equation:

```
integrate(exp(-x**2), (x, c, -c))=1/2
```

which should look like this:

[image: integral with limits]

How can I find a solution for `c`, for example using a library such as sympy?

Comment: This post is too general for stackoverflow, you can only ask specific coding questions. I suggest, you read about [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html)

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Sympy you can do the following:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x, c

sol = solve(Eq(integrate(exp(-x**2), (x,c,-c)), S(1)/2))
print("symbolic solution:", sol)
print("numeric solution:", [s.evalf() for s in sol])
```

Output:

```
symbolic solution: [erfinv(-1/(2*sqrt(pi)))]
numeric solution: [-0.255449286541000]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Or were you looking for some other approach?